# Импорт в python

Tags: python

Доброго времени суток. Я только начинаю знакомиться с Python и столкнулся с проблемой подгрузки собственного конфига.

**index.py:**

```
if os.path.exists(config["pagedir"] + params["id"] + ".py"):
    __import__(string.replace(config["pagedir"], "/", ".") + params["id"])
print page # не работает
```

**pages/index.py:**

```
page = {
"tpl": "page.html",
"title": "index",
"html": "<b>Index</b> page"
}
#print page - работает даже после импорта
```

Собственно, вопрос: а как достучаться до page?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Можно поинтересоваться, для чего вам такая страшная конструкция? Чем вас не устроил обычный статический импорт и/или обычный конфиг в yaml (json, xml, etc) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
module = __import__(config["pagedir"].replace("/", ".") + params["id"], fromlist=True)
print module.page
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. =)